# Are Kibana, Grafana and Stage monitor forked from same Open Source project?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, grafana

All three - Kibana, Grafana and Stage monitor have similar view but don't have a common open source dashboard that doesn't come with integration to database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes also check out kibana 4 which has some enhancements. Also be specific in your queries.